# How to use CustomJsonParser to parse json string in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: json, apache-spark, parsing, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Instead of parsing whole JSON string, user will provide a CustomJsonParser to parse partial JSON string into CustomObject. How to use this CustomJsonParser to convert JSON string in Spark Structured Streaming instead of using **from_json** and **get_json_object** methods?

Sample Code like this:

```
val jsonDF = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kakfaBrokers)
            .option("subscribe", kafkaConsumeTopicName)
            .option("group.id", kafkaConsumerGroupId)
            .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets)
            .option("auto.offset.reset", autoOffsetReset)
            .option("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer].getName)
            .option("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer].getName)
            .option("enable.auto.commit", "false")
            .load()

val messagesDF = jsonDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

spark.udf.register("parseJson", (json: String) =>
    customJsonParser.parseJson(json)
)

val objDF = messagesDF.selectExpr("""parseJson(value) AS message""")

val query = objDF.writeStream
            .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
            .format("console")
            .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

It runs with the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Schema for type com.xxx.xxxEntity is not supported    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:693)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.register(UDFRegistration.scala:159)

Comment: What's the return type of `customJsonParser.parseJson`? You may want to use a case class.